# Get the Time of the Last change password for Windows machine with out using command line

Tags: windows, cmd, c#-3.0

I need a solution for the system when the password is changed without using a command line because I have tried already as the below command:

```
**net user rlkar**

User name rlkar

Full Name karthik ravi

Comment                      
User's comment               
Country/region code          000 (System Default)
Account active               Yes
Account expires              Never

Password last set            20-11-2017 18:57:59
Password expires             18-02-2018 18:57:59
Password changeable          25-11-2017 18:57:59
Password required            Yes
User may change password     Yes

Workstations allowed         All

Logon   script                 
User profile                 
Home directory

Lastlogon    Never

Logon hours allowed          All

Local Group Memberships      *Administrators       *HomeUsers            
                             *Performance Log Users*SophosAdministrator  
                             *SophosUser           *Users                
Global Group memberships     *None     

**but for some of the systems it is in different language.**

ex: 

Nombre de usuario                          BPINZON
Nombre completo                            
Comentario                                 
Comentario del usuario                     
Código de país                             000 (Predeterminado por el equipo)
Cuenta activa                              Sí
La cuenta expira                           Nunca

Ultimo cambio de contraseña                25/10/2017 09:18:19 a.m.
La contraseña expira                       Nunca
Cambio de contraseña                       25/10/2017 09:18:19 a.m.
Contraseña requerida                       No
El usuario puede cambiar la contraseña     Sí

Estaciones de trabajo autorizadas          Todas
Script de inicio de sesión                 
Perfil de usuario                          
Directorio principal                       
Ultima sesión iniciada                     04/02/2018 11:33:14 p.m.

Horas de inicio de sesión autorizadas      Todas

Miembros del grupo local                   *Administradores      
Miembros del grupo global                  *None                 
Se ha completado el comando correctamente.
```

So that I can't read the data in which I want exactly.

EX: Password last set

**So anyone please suggest overcoming the above problem which the solution to be in generic.**

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
get-aduser -filter * -properties passwordlastset, passwordneverexpires |ft Name, passwordlastset, Passwordneverexpires
```

Export the list to CSV:

```
Get-ADUser -filter * -properties passwordlastset, passwordneverexpires | sort-object name | select-object Name, passwordlastset, passwordneverexpires | Export-csv -path c:\temp\user-password-info-20131119.csv
```

Also check this [article](https://www.lepide.com/how-to/track-password-changes-and-resets-in-active-directory.html) to detect password changes using native auditing.